# In Liferay with hsql: Where is the database file

Tags: database, liferay, hsqldb

I am using Liferay with Apache Tomcat and hsql. I need to locate the database file that is used. According to hsql documentation there should be a file lportal.data in the directory data/hsql, but there isn't one.

Comment: What are the contents of the `data/hsql` directory?

Comment: there's lportal.lck, lportal.log, lportal.properties and lportal.script.

Comment: That *is* the hibernate database. The `.script` file contains the data as SQL, the `.log` that last actions that took place, the `.properties` the configuration and the `.lck` is the db lockfile. These *are* *the* database, hsql has nothing like one big `.data`file.

Comment: @marc please add your comment to an answer - there is no .data file because Liferay is configured to use MEMORY tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hibernate database consists of 4 files.

The .script file contains the data as SQL, the .log that last actions that took place, the .properties the configuration and the .lck is the db lockfile.

These are the database, hsql has nothing like one big .data file. All other constructs that are typical for a database are generated and only in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Connection line `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/D:/Coding/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/data/hsql/lportal` for Squirrel SQL Client (Liferay on Apache Tomcat)

Comment: This still the same for Liferay 7.3 and 7.4 in  2023. Thank you