# Liferay Error, this site is inactive. Please contact the administrator

Tags: jboss, liferay, portal

Hi I am testing Liferay Portal however I can no longer access the Portal - when I now access the Portal I get the following message

```
This site is inactive. Please contact the administrator.
```

I believe what has happened is I have made the site inactive in the control panel however I can no longer access the control panel. I use internal liferay database, not MySQL.

If there are any suggestions how I can get round this to reactivate the site it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete the database and restart the server or you can access the `HSQL` database using a command line tool like you would with `SQLite`.

Chances are you don't have the command line tools to access the `HSQL` data store so you can download them here:

http://hsqldb.org/

`DatabaseManager` is what you are looking for in particular.

The location of the DB file can be found in the following answer:

[In Liferay with hsql: Where is the database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826868/in-liferay-with-hsql-where-is-the-database-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to access direct the control panel with:

```
http://host:port/group/control_panel/manage
```

e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/group/control_panel/manage
```